# Covert Object type to Pure String in Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, object, lambda

In my data frame there are two columns and they are obj type.

| index | COLOUR | CATEGORY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | blue | iphone11 |
| 1 | black | iphone12 |

```
iphone_sale['COLOUR'] = iphone_sale['COLOUR'].astype(str)
iphone_sale['CATEGORY'] = iphone_sale['CATEGORY'].astype(str)
```

I need to create a new column using above both columns.

```
iphone_sales_sum["colour_category"] = iphone_sales_sum.apply(lambda x: f"{x['COLOUR']} /{x['CATEGORY']}", axis=1)
```

But I am getting a noisy values as the derived column.

iphone 12\nName: 0, dtype: object/...   etc

But it doesn't give any error i lmbda function.This code perfectly worked for an other scenario.

Comment: what do you mean  with noisy values

Comment: @NikolayTsvetanov iphone 12\nName: 0, dtype: object/..blue\nName: 0, dtype: object/ Values in derived column are like this

Answer (score 1):

when i reproduce your code:

```
import pandas as pd
iphone_sales_sum = pd.DataFrame([[1,"blue", "iphone 12"],[2,"black","iphone12"],[3,"sad3","jkl3"]], columns=["index",'COLOUR', 'CATEGORY' ])
iphone_sales_sum['COLOUR'] = iphone_sales_sum['COLOUR'].astype(str)
iphone_sales_sum['CATEGORY'] = iphone_sales_sum['CATEGORY'].astype(str)
iphone_sales_sum['colour_category'] = iphone_sales_sum.apply(lambda x: f"{x['COLOUR']} / {x['CATEGORY']}", axis=1)
```

i get

```
colour_category
blue / iphone 12
black / iphone12
sad3 / jkl3
```